# My own shell can't perform a search, when it is invoked the 2nd time

Tags: c, shell, search, directory

When I give my shell 'ls' as the first argument it works fine, but when I put it through the 2nd time, without terminating a shell, it either can't find the file or gives me a segmentation fault. I'm sure it has something to do with the while loop. I tried setting i back to 0 at the end of the function, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Here's my search function

```
int searchForFile(int argc, char *argv[]) {
DIR* dir;           // Var for scanned directory.
struct dirent* entry;       // Var for one directory entry.
char* fileName = argv[0];

int i = 0;
char** directoryArray = tokenised(PATH);

while(directoryArray[i] != NULL) {
    printf("Searching directory: '%s'\n", directoryArray[i]);
    dir = opendir(directoryArray[i]);
    if(!dir) {
        perror("Can't open the directory");
        return 0;
    }

    while((entry = readdir(dir))) {
        //Compare the entry's name with fileName
        if(strcmp(entry->d_name, fileName) == 0) {
            printf("Found: Address is '%s/%s'\n", directoryArray[i], entry->d_name);
            //Form an address out 2 strings
            char *address = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(directoryArray[i])+sizeof(char)*strlen(entry->d_name)+2*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(address, directoryArray[i]);
            strcat(address, "/");
            strcat(address, fileName);
            argv[0] = address;
            i = 0;
            execute(argc, argv);

            //Free memory
            int j = 0;
            while(directoryArray[j] != NULL) {
                free(directoryArray[j]);
                j++;
            }
            free(directoryArray);
            //free(address);
            closedir(dir);
            return 1;
        }

    }
    closedir(dir);
    i++;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: you should give more code and/or details. How this function is called? How do you read commands… By the way you also seems to have some global variables. Whatever having a segfault probably means that you do something bad with buffers. Try to debug (do you have valgrind?).

Comment: We have no way to be confident how "giv[ing] my shell 'ls' as the first argument" or "put[ting] it through the 2nd time, without terminating a shell" corresponds to calls to the function you presented.  We have no way to check what functions `tokenised()` and `execute()` do.  I'm not seeing an obvious error in the code you presented, so we probably cannot help you.  If you want our help then present minimal, complete code and inputs with which we can reproduce your problem.